# How do I properly declare this variable?

Tags: c, function, variables, syntax

I am trying to write a program in C that takes a positive integer that is input and then counts down to zero and back up to the number by 1. I am getting errors when trying to run the code saying that my variables usernum and usernum2 are undeclared. In the main function I declare them both as integers so what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

```
`
void loop_down_to_zero(){
    while (usernum2 >= 0){
       printf("%d\n", &usernum2);
       usernum2--;
       if (usernum2 ==0) {
          printf("****\n");
       }
    }
}
void loop_up_to_zero(){
    while (usernum2 < usernum){
       usernum2++;
       printf("%d\n", usernum2);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
   int usernum;
   int usernum2;
   usernum2 = usernum;
   printf("Enter a positive integer: \n");
   scanf("%d", &usernum);
   while (usernum <= 0){
      printf("Error, enter a positive integer: \n");
      scanf("%d", &usernum);
   }
   if (usernum > 0) {
      loop_down_to_zero();
      loop_up_to_zero();
   }
}
`
```

I tried moving the void functions below main because I am still trying to figure out some of the syntax in C but it did not appear to have much of an impact.

Comment: `usernum` and `usernum2` are local variables in the `int main` function, not accessible from the other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `usernum2 = usernum` you're trying to assign value in `usernum` to `usernum2`. But in `usernum` there's no value at that moment, because you've only *declared* the variable `usernum`, you've never *defined* it. Example of *declaration:* `int usernum;`. Example of *definition:* `int usernum = 0;`

Also, in your line `printf("%d\n", &usernum2);` you shouldn't pass the *address*, you should pass the *value:* `printf("%d\n", usernum2);`

Comment: Ok so I made some fixes and my program runs almost as intended now, it does not print the numbers counting down for some reason ex. input is 5 it outputs 0 **** 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Ended up moving my usernum = usernum2 into the if statement that calls the other functions and it seemed to work, thanks for the help!

Comment: inside a function, `int usernum;` is a definition, not just a declaration.

Comment: This answer does not address the fundamental problem of the program, that the values needed in the functions are not made available to them (e.g., not passed as parameters).

Answer (score 0):

it's not enough do declare your variables in main, you have to declare then both functions, and you also should send your user input as a parameter to the functions.Also you shouldn't print &, this will print the memory address.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void loop_down_to_zero( int usernum ){
while (usernum >= 0){
   printf("%d\n", usernum);
   usernum--;
   if (usernum ==0) {
      printf("****\n");
   }
}}


    void loop_up_to_zero(int usernum,int usernum2){
while (usernum2 < usernum){
   usernum2++;
   printf("%d\n", usernum2);
}}

    int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int usernum;
    printf("Enter a positive integer: \n");
    scanf("%d", &usernum);
    while (usernum <= 0){
    printf("Error, enter a positive integer: \n");
    scanf("%d", &usernum);
    }
    usernum;
    if (usernum > 0) {
    loop_down_to_zero(usernum);
    loop_up_to_zero(usernum,0);
    }}
```